# Determining the best audio quality

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing

How can you determine the best audio quality in a list of audio files of the same audio clip, **with out looking at the audio file's header**.  The tricky part is that all of the files came from different formats and bit rates and they where all [transcoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcode) to the same format and bit rate.  How can this be done efficiently?

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you allowed to look at the samples of the audio themselves, but not the header?

Comment: @dmazzoni  well the headers on all of the files will be identical so its not going to help.  But yeah you have the full files, including the (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation).

Comment: Are you sure about the "A human can tell the difference" part? Compressed audio files sometimes (esp. when the bitrate isn't too low) sound better to some people than the original. If you're talking about big differences in quality, then that's another thing.

Comment: @Tomer Vromen  I edited my post,  there are cases where i can clearly tell that something is wrong with the audio but a computer should be better at this.

Comment: During transcoding, were the audio files upsampled? E.g. converting 8-bit 11kHz to 16-bit 44kHz?

Comment: @mdma  I'm interested in both up sampling and down sampling.

Comment: What is the common format & bitrate?

Comment: @Seth   mp3 is popular,  you can assume that if it helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many of the answers outlined here refer to common audio measurements such as THD+N, SNR, etc.  However, these do not always correlate well with human hearing of audio artifacts.  Lossy audio compression techniques typically function by *increasing* THD+N and SNR, but aim to do so in ways that are difficult for the human ear to detect.  A more traditional audio measurement technique may find decreased SNR in a certain frequency band, but does that matter if there's so much energy in adjacent bands that no one would ever notice the difference?

The  research paper titled "[A Perceptual Audio Quality Measure Based on a Psychoacoustic Sound Representation](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=7019)" outlines an algorithm for quantifying the ability of the human ear to detect audible differences, based on a model of how the ear hears.  It takes into factors that do correlate with audio quality as perceived by humans.  The paper includes a study comparing their algorithm's results to subjective double-blind testing, to give you an idea of how well their model works.

I could not find a free copy of this paper but a decent university library should have it on file.

Implementing the algorithm would require some knowledge of audio signal processing in the frequency domain.  An undergraduate with DSP experience should be able to implement it.  If you don't have the reference waveform, you could use information in this paper to quantify how objectionable artifacts may be.

The algorithm would work on PCM audio, preferably time-aligned, and certainly does not require knowledge of the file type or header.

Comment: The algorithm assumes a reference waveform is available, but many of the measurements don't necessarily require a reference waveform and could be applied generally.  Another option would be to compute the quality measurement using every waveform as a trial reference.  The waveform that yields the largest quality differences is the best one.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a software developer (I'm an audio engineer) and what you hear when you compress with mp3 algorithms is:
- less high frequencies: so you can check a loss in the energy of the higher range
- distorted stereo: so you can make a Mid/Side matrix, and check for the THD in the Side
- less phase coherency: maybe you can check that with a correlation meter

Hope it helps, it's a difficult task for a computer!

Answer (score 9):

First, **I'm not an audio engineer**, but I've been trying to keep in touch about audio compression in general because I have a big mp3 collection and I have some thoughts to share about the subject.

Is the best audio quality that you're looking for from an human perspective? If so, you can't measure by "objective means" like comparing spectograms and such.

If a spectogram is ugly, it **doesn't necessarily** mean the quality is terrible. What matters is if someone can distinguish an encoded file from an original source doing a blind test. Period. If you want to check the quality of an encoded audio track you have to conduct [a blind ABX test](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=16295).

> LAME (and all other kinds of lossy
>   MP3, AAC, AC3, DTS, ATRAC...
>   compressors) is so called perceptual
>   coder. It exploits certain facts about
>   the nature of human audio perception.
>   So, you cannot rely simply on
>   spectrograms to evaluate its quality.

[Source](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=54707&view=findpost&p=490473)

Now, if your objectives are from objective manners/perspectives, you could use [EAQUAL](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=EAQUAL), which stands for Evaluation Of Audio Quality:

> It's an objective measurement
>   technique used to measure the quality
>   of encoded/decoded audio files (very
>   similiar to PEAQ)
>
> (...)
>
> The results, however when using
>   objective testing methodologies are
>   still inconclusive and mostly only
>   used by codec developers and
>   researchers.

...or [Friedman statistical analysis tool](http://www.rarewares.org/others.php#friedman).

> (...) performs several statistical
>   analysis on data sets, which is
>   particularly suited for listening test
>   data.

**I'm not saying that spectrum analyzers are useless.** That's why I posted some utilities. I'm just saying to be careful with all these statistical methods: as someone at the Hydrogenaudio community [said once](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=54707&view=findpost&p=490499), **You don't listen with your eyes.** (check this thread I posted as well, it's a great resource). To really prove audio quality from an human perspective, you should test ears and not graphs.

This is a complicated subject, and IMHO I suggest you to look for a specialized audio community like [Hydrogenaudio](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/).

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of audio files that started in different formats with varying quality. They've all been converted to the same format, so you can't use the header to figure out which ones were originally high quality and which ones weren't.

This is a hard problem. There are potentially a few tricks that could catch some quality problems, but detecting, say, something that was converted from a low-bitrate compression algorithm like MP3 would be very hard.

Some easy tricks:

- Check the maximum amplitude - if it's low, the quality won't be good.
- Measure the highest frequency - if it's low, the original might have had a lower sample rate.

Comment: +1 you do understand the problem, and i agree it is difficult.

Comment: +1 for fairly simple tests for finding likely indicators of low quality

Answer (score 4):

If you have the original you can estimate how it was altered by estimating a transfer function. You will need to assume some model, maybe start with a low-pass filter, add some smudging (convolution) and then run an estimator to produce a measure of quality. You could look around on the wikipedia article on [Estimation_theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory)

Answer (score 1):

I think that disown's answer is good, assuming that you are just trying to estimate a set of parameters. Unfortunately, you also have to define a comparison function for the parameters you have estimated.

What happens if two compressions have both applied a [band-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter) with equally large frequency ranges, but one of the admits higher frequencies than the other. Is one of them better? Which one?

The answer probably depends on which frequencies are being used more in the files you are working with.

An objective measure would be to see which file has lost less [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). Unfortunately, this is not easy to do correctly.

Comment: Adding pure noise would even increase the entropy - that measure does not seem appropriate for perceptual audio quality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure about this, but here's a good place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio

I don't think you can calculate SNR from one signal, but if you have a collection of signals then you might be able to work out the SNR comparing all of them.

There are some interesting links at the bottom of the page which could provide some routes of interest as well if that isn't possible.

Also, I'm not an audio engineer, but I know a little about signal processing, is there any way you can measure quantisation levels in audio signals?  Perhaps something to look into.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the original audio, this is probably a lot of work; it's almost certainly fundamentally impossible in an absolute sense since you can't tell which track's peculiarities are intentional and which bogus.  You may even have encodings from different recordings or mixes, in which case plain comparison is fairly meaningless in any case.

Thus, assuming you do *not* have the original, the best you can probably do is a heuristic approach - which will probably work quite well, but be a lot of effort to implement.

- Invest in some audio-processing software and skill; use this to build software to identify common encoder defects heuristically based solely on the output.  Such defects might be poor temporal locality of sound hits (suggestion overlarge windows in the compression), high correlation between left and right signals, limited frequency range, etc. (a person with the right experience can probably list dozens).
- Rate the quality of the audio on each heuristic on some sliding scale.
- Use common sense and as much time+people for testing as you have to weigh the various factors for relevance.  For example, while it might be nice to have frequency reproduction up to 24Khz, it's not very important; on the other had lack of sharpness may be more annoying.

If you're lucky, someone's done the job before you, because this sounds like an expensive proposition.

Answer (score 1):

**A New Perceptual Quality Measure for
Bit Rate Reduced Audio**
http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/cache/papers/cs/15888/http:zSzzSzwww-ft.ee.tu-berlin.dezSzPublikationenzSzpaperszSzAES1996Copenhagen.pdf/a-new-perceptual-quality.pdf

> Perceptual audio coding algorithms
>   perform a drastic irrelevancy
>   reduction in order to achieve a high
>   coding gain. Signal components that
>   are assumed to be unperceivable are
>   not transmitted and the coding noise
>   is spectrally shaped according to the
>   masking threshold of the audio signal.
>   Simple quality measures (e.g. signal
>   to noise ratio, harmonic distortions),
>   which can not separate these inaudible
>   artefacts from audible errors, can not
>   be used to assess the performance of
>   such coders.
>
> For the quality evaluation of
>   perceptual audio codecs, appropriate
>   measurement algorithms are needed,
>   which detect and assess audible
>   artefacts by comparing the output of
>   the codec with the uncoded reference.
>   A filter bank based perceptual model
>   is presented, which yields better
>   temporal resolution than FFT-based
>   approaches and thus allows a more
>   precise modelling of pre- and
>   post-masking and a refined analysis of
>   the envelopes within each filter
>   channel.

**See Also**
http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/201987.aspx?viewType=1

Comment: Wow,  its good to see some solid research come from Microsoft.